# Talend: how to generate Java code from javajet templates and properties of a job?

Tags: talend

Talend Data Integration studio, more than anything else, is a code generator. When I design a job in the studio using components from the Palette and run it, Talend combines {javajet template, xml, properties} files of the job and generates a single Java file for the job.

My question: Can I know the process of Java code generation from the javajet templates and properties files? Can I know the commands that are used?

Why I want to know?

I have a hundred jobs but the design of all the jobs are same and only a few parameters change from job to job. Instead of creating all the hundred jobs and later maintaining them, I want to create one job and replicate it after substituting the parameters read from a file. This drastically reduces development time and eases maintenance.

So, if I know the code generation process, I can programmatically read the parameters from a file and generate all the hundred job {javajet template, xml, properties} folders and then use the code generation command to generate the final Java code which can later be built and run.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you're using the enterprise version you can use JobScripts (I haven't used them but you can)
http://beyondetl.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/JobScript%20create
https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=11713#p11713

Comment: I am using Open studio.

Answer (score 1):

I'd second the suggestion to use JobScripts and perhaps look into using Joblets...

https://help.talend.com/display/TalendDataFabricStudioUserGuide62EN/4.4+Creating+a+Job+using+a+Job+creation+API

https://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?idTuto=39